# ES File Explorer Pro: root access error on Android 6

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, es-file-explorer

When I try to enable **Root Explorer** in [ES File Explorer/Manager PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop.pro) 1.0.7 there is a error toast notification saying that...

`Sorry test failed. This feature cannot run on your phone.`

I'm using a rooted OnePlus Two with OxygenOS 3.0.2 / Android 6.0.1.

Can this error be solved somehow by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Install [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) and [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm).
2. Open the terminal app and write these commands "enter" separated: `su`, `mount -o remount,rw /system`, `touch /sbin/su /system/bin/su /system/xbin/su`, `mount -o remount,ro /system`, `exit`.
3. Reboot

Now you can enable the **Root Explorer** feature in ES File Explorer without any error!

Comment: Credits go to [Maik F.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop.pro&reviewId=Z3A6QU9xcFRPSF9DUllVQWF3c1N2Q2xBdHR2a2JNcVV4Z0MzT2FKQWw0M1R6d2RpUnYzcGFoTVFsWV9yYmEwUEJfS3ZYd3Bsa2dxaGRHd0xVN3o2UVFhS1dR)!